# Azure DevOps - Private NuGet feed doesn't update stable release

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

I created a private NuGet feed in Azure DevOps following [this guide](https://medium.com/medialesson/get-started-with-private-nuget-feeds-in-azure-devops-8c7b5f022a68) and created a build pipeline with `dotnet pack` and `dotnet nuget push` steps. After running the build a few times, the new versions are displayed under `Artifacts` >> `MyFeed` >> `Versions`. I promoted some of the versions by hand to `@Release`.

Here's the view in DevOps:
[image: DevOps NuGet feed details]

But when I connect to the feed in Visual Studio, I only see version `1.0.0` as stable release, but all later versions (which are published via my build pipeline), are only shown if I check the "include pre-release" option. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Visual Studio NuGet package details]

My questions are:

1 - how can I manually promote a version to stable?
2 - how can I promote a version to stable via a build or release pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure DevOps - Private NuGet feed doesn't update stable release

Just like zivkan said "*anything after a `-` character signals pre-release information.*". You can check the nuget document [Package versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#pre-release-versions) for some details.

> 1 - how can I manually promote a version to stable?

You can download that package from your nuget feed, then change the package version to stable, then re-push it to the feed.

> 2 - how can I promote a version to stable via a build or release pipeline?

To promote a version to stable via a build or release, you could change the build number. When you use `dotnet pack` task to create the nuget package, there is an option **Automatic package versioning**:

[image]

**Update:**

So, try to use the option **Use the build number** option on the Automatic package versioning.

Then, in the Build number format option, you can set it to `$(Major).$(Minor).$(Patch)$(Rev:.r)`:

[image]

The value of `$(Major)`, `$(Minor)`, `$(Patch)` are custom variables in the Variables tab, the value of `$(Rev:.r)` is the build number.

In this case, the package will be `TestSample.1.0.0.5.nupkg`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right. So if I want to publish from a pipeline, I should not pick the `date and time` option, since it automatically adds the extra `-ci...` to the package version. Also, the `@prerelease` and `@release` flags represent a different concept and have nothing to do with a package being "stable". Is that correct?

Comment: @Szeki, yes, you can check my updated answer for more details, hope this can helps.

Answer (score 1):

NuGet uses Semantic Versioning 2.0, which says that anything after a `-` character signals pre-release information. Therefore `1.0.1-CI` is prerelease, whereas `1.0.1` would be a release version. If you want build metadata in the version string, you should use the `+` character, again as defined by SemVer2.

edit: note that SemVer metadata does not contribute to version comparisons, so `1.2.3+CI.1` is considered the SAME version as `1.2.3+CI.2`